# Agregar CSS con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

JS

```
<script>
var estilos  = ["https://www.mexicodestinos.com/Content/StyleMD/a-hotels-md/general.min.css?1.0.8","https://www.mexicodestinos.com/Content/plugings/slick-1.5.7/slick/slick.min.css",
"https://www.mexicodestinos.com/Content/css/statica/general.min.css?1.0.0.7","https://www.mexicodestinos.com/Content/StyleMD/a-hotels-md/general.min.css?1.0.8"];
var tamanioEstilos = estilos.length;
var TamanioEstilosHtml  = document.styleSheets.length;
var bandera=0;
for(i=0;i<tamanioEstilos;i++)
{
for(y=0;y<TamanioEstilosHtml;y++){
if(estilos[i] != document.styleSheets[y].href){bandera=1;}
}
if(bandera==1){
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].append("<link href='"+estilos[i]+"' rel='stylesheet'>");
console.log("sepuso"+ y);
}bandera=0;
}
</script>
```

Cómo le agrego el link que haga falta, de este modo, no se agrega, es para un widget

Comment: Hola Ernesto, tienes alguna buena razón para cargar el CSS dinámicamente?

Comment: Como dice @CarlosMuñoz, no le veo mucho sentido a proceder de esa manera.

Comment: si, si lo tengo ;)

Comment: @ErnestoEmmanuelYahLopez Lo que desean los amigos arriba, es que coloques el motivo por que quieres hacer esto, ya que, no es muy usual hacer este tipo de cosas, ademas, considero que en ser este el caso, puede haber una solución mejor.

Comment: Una mejor solución?
Eso es lo que busco :'(

Comment: ¿Porqué queres cargar el CSS de forma dinámica?

Comment: Ya lo hice gracias, ya me funcionó, me dejaron morir :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes validarlo revisando la propiedad `href` de los elementos del array:

```
document.styleSheets
```

Ejemplo

```
function addcss () {
    var url = "<url del css>";
    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++ ) {
        if ( document.styleSheets[i].href === url) return;
    }

    var csslink = document.createElement("link");
    csslink.rel = "stylesheet";
    csslink.type = "text/css";
    csslink.href = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(csslink);
}
```

Comment: Gracias, crees que sea conveniente poner en un array todos los css que tiene que comparar, y hacer ciclos para comparar

Comment: es decir, son varios estilos que tengo que comparar para ver si existen en el HTML